# Update variables after arr.splice()

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array that I am using to populate div's and assign their ID's with numbers based on where they lie in the array.

I am able to remove a section using `.splice()`, but after I remove the element, the ID's remain the same on the element, (which is affecting how I delete subsequent items in the same array) until I refresh the page.

For example it starts out as

```
<div id="favorites-1"></div>
<div id="favorites-2"></div>
<div id="favorites-3"></div>
```

when I remove one of the divs, say `<div id="favorites-1"></div>` I would like `<div id="favorites-2"></div>` to now become the new `<div id="favorites-1"></div>` and the favorites-3 to becomes favorites-2.

If i remove the elements from right to left it works. If i remove the elements from left to right, only the first element is actually removed.

How can I update the ID numbers based on their location with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: It's sounds like you have a JavaScript array, not a JSON array. JSON is a general purpose textual data-exchange format. While it's certainly possible to do this "manually", in the long run it might make sense to use a library which automatically updates the HTML (the view) based on your data (the model). Have a look at http://knockoutjs.com/ or http://facebook.github.io/react/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//splice the array
arr.splice(x,y,replacements)
//iterate from the first modified item in the list and set the correct ID 
for(var i=x; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].id = "favorites-"+i;
}
```

is the manual way.

But if you want to do a lot of things like this, I'd recommend using Knockout.js or a similar library.  With knockout, you'd have an observable array of items which you could add items to, and you could map the id to the index of the element in an automatic way.  For instance it might look something like this.

```
<!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
<div data-bind="attr:{id:'favorites-'+$index"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You can also do this with other libraries such as AngularJS or EmberJS, but knockout is a focused library for the particular problem of binding your data-model to the DOM.

Comment: run this on click (of element removal)?

Comment: Perfect. it took some tinkering to get it the way I needed it to, but it works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Don't you think it's weird to have mutating IDs in the DOM?

Comment: It is a bit, but I need it this way to remove elements correctly. If id's don;t update the wrong objects get removed from my array.

Comment: @EHerman maybe consider not using IDs as your keys then?  Something like knockout or angular will let you separate your DOM semantics from your model so that you can just work on your data without having to manually update the DOM like this everywhere.  The DOM makes a crappy model, and using it that way tightly binds your presentation code to your logic in a way that can cause issues (like having to do the stupid loop here)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a sparse array with [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) (then you wouldn't need to change your elements' IDs):

```
var a = [0,1,2,3];
delete a[1]; // Key "1" was deleted
```

#### Caveat

The length of the array will still be `4`, even without the `1` key. If you're looping the array based on length, you'll get `undefined` for `a[1]`. If you iterate with `for..in`, you'll skip from key `"0"` to `"2"`, but [that might cause other problems](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F500504%2Fwhy-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea&ei=QwClUs-PKYfQkQffs4HIDg&usg=AFQjCNGZ2O6HZA20l2gys69Wxwj1e6oSSw&sig2=WP853RtVls9yIHvqo7sUww&bvm=bv.57752919,d.eW0)...

Comment: Also then `a.hasOwnProperty(1)` will be false

Comment: @Doorknob True, that check would be mandatory when iterating with `for..in`.